# Android: Start main activity when pressing Back Button

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I need help with this activity thing.. I have a main activity and when a button is clicked a new activity starts and the main activity finishes. What I want is to start аgain the main activity when the back button is pressed in the second activity. Or if you can tell me a another way to refresh the main activity when I turn back from the second, without adding a new activity in the stack. I will really appreciate your help. Thank you :)

P.s: I need to tell you that my activity extends ActionBarActivity, not Activity so I'm not pretty sure how to override onBackPressed() if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a up navigation by adding a parent activity. This also improves the overall navigation experience for the user.

See - http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, Another.class);
    context.startActivity(newIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    finish();
```

you can start your your new activity from 'Main' using the above code. The 'finish()' call would remove the Main Activity from the stack.

Then in your new activity you can do this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
    context.startActivity(newIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: context should be declared like this, right? 
Context context = getApplicationContext();
if yes, i don't tha have startActivityForResult() method

Comment: context is the context of your activity that is calling the function. 
i.e. 'this'. You can get the context of your activity inside onCreate, using Context context = this. Use this context in code.

Comment: As I said, I don't have such method as context.startActivityForResult()

Comment: what does your Main Activity extend ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49906/discussion-between-geekoraul-and-user3132352)